# Moving in a 2d array board and preventing player from moving off board

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a basic game from an exercise I found online. I used a 2D array for the dungeon map. Now for the player movement, I want to prevent the player from moving off the board so I made the function `playerPositionLimiter`. This worked and the playerX and playerY did not go above 9.[board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrRpO.png)

```
void playerPositionLimiter(){
    //The if condition below prevents the player to move off the board
    if((playerX>9||playerY>9)||(playerX<0||playerY<0)){
        if(playerX>9) playerX=9;
        else if(playerX<0) playerX=0;
        else if(playerY>9) playerY=9;
        else if(playerY<0) playerY=0;
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to use the same function to prevent the enemyX and Y postions from moving off board so I changed the code to

```
void playerPositionLimiter(int posX, int posY){
//Prevents the player from moving off the board
if((posX>9||posY>9)||(posX<0||posY<0)){
    if(posX>9) posX=9;
    else if(posX<0) posX=0;
    else if(posY>9) posY=9;
    else if(posY<0) posY=0;
}}
```

Now if I keep moving right the X value goes on increasing and moves to the line below after it exceeds 9.[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKKrm.png)

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
/* Dungeon Crawl*/
/*Player variables*/
int turn=0;
int playerXprev;
int playerYprev;
int playerX=0;
int playerY=0;
int enemyX=rand()%10+1;
int enemyY=rand()%10+1;
/*Game variables*/
bool gameOver=false;
//Declaring functions
void gameScreenUpdate();
void playerMovementHandling();
//
// Char array for dungeon map
char dungeonMap[10][10]={
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','T','.','.','T','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','T','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','T','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','T','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','X'},
};
// Function for printing the map
void printDungeonMap(){
    int dR=0;
    while(dR<10){
        for(int dC=0;dC<10;dC++){
            cout << dungeonMap[dR][dC];
        }
        cout << endl;
        dR++;
    }
}
// Sets the position of player in array and clears the previous position
void playerPositionPrint(){
    dungeonMap[playerYprev][playerXprev]='.';
    dungeonMap[playerY][playerX]='P';
}
// Prevents the player to move off the grid
/*
void playerPositionLimiter(){
    //The if condition below prevents the player to move off the board
    if((playerX>9||playerY>9)||(playerX<0||playerY<0)){
        if(playerX>9) playerX=9;
        else if(playerX<0) playerX=0;
        else if(playerY>9) playerY=9;
        else if(playerY<0) playerY=0;
    }
}
*/

void playerPositionLimiter(int posY, int posX){
    //Prevents the player from moving off the board
        if(posX>9) posX=9;
        if(posX<0) posX=0;
        if(posY>9) posY=9;
        if(posY<0) posY=0;
}

// Game Conditions status | checking for winning / losing condition
void checkPlayerCondition(){
    string gameMessage;
/*
switch (dungeonMap[playerX][playerY]){
case 'X':
gameMessage = "You win!";
gameOver=true;
break;
case 'E':
gameMessage = "You ran into an enemy and died!";
gameOver=true;
break;
case 'T':
gameMessage = "You ran into a trap and died!";
gameOver=true;
break;
case '.':
gameOver=false;
break;
default:
gameOver=false;
}*/

    if(dungeonMap[playerY][playerX]=='X'){
        //gameScreenUpdate();
        gameMessage = "You win!";
        gameOver=true;
    }else if(dungeonMap[playerY][playerX]=='E'){
        //gameScreenUpdate();
        gameMessage = "You ran into an enemy and died!";
        gameOver=true;
    }else if(dungeonMap[playerY][playerX]=='T'){
        //gameScreenUpdate();
        gameMessage = "You ran into a trap and died!";
        gameOver=true;
    }else if(dungeonMap[playerY][playerX]=='.'){
        //gameScreenUpdate();
        gameOver=false;
    }
    gameScreenUpdate();
    cout << gameMessage;
}
// Takes user input and changes the X Y co-ordinates of the player
void userInputHandling(){
    playerXprev=playerX;
    playerYprev=playerY;
    char playerChar;
    cout << "Next move: ";
    playerChar=_getch();
    switch (playerChar){
    case 'w':
    playerY--;
    break;
    case 's':
    playerY++;
    break;
    case 'd':
    playerX++;
    break;
    case 'a':
    playerX--;
    break;
    default:
    cout << "(w/a/s/d)" << endl;
    userInputHandling();
}
}
// Takes user input -> checks whether player position is in limits -> checks player conditions(game conditions)
void playerPositionHandling(){
    userInputHandling();
    playerPositionLimiter(playerX,playerY);
    checkPlayerCondition();
}
//gameScreenUpdate clears and updates game screen
void gameScreenUpdate(){
    system("cls");
    playerPositionPrint();
    printDungeonMap();
}
// Moving enemies
void enemyPosition(){
    dungeonMap[enemyX][enemyY] = 'E';
}
// Move enemy
/*
void moveEnemy(){
    if(turn%5){
        dungeonMap[enemyY][enemyX]='.';
        enemyX=enemyX+(rand()%1+(-1));
        enemyY=enemyY+(rand()%1+(-1));
    }
    enemyPosition();
}*/
// Prints the game screen for the first time then loops till game over is true
int main(){
    srand(632);
    enemyPosition();
    gameScreenUpdate();
    while(!gameOver){
    playerPositionHandling();
    //moveEnemy();
    turn++;
    //cout << turn;
    cout << "X:" << playerX;
    cout << "Y:" << playerY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Remove this if statement: `if((posX>9||posY>9)||(posX<0||posY<0)){` and turn all else if statement into if statements: `if(posX<0) posX=0;`, `if(posY>9) posY=9;`, `if(posY<0) posY=0;`.

Comment: @dimchtzThat did not help. I added the full code because I think the issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: Well, `playerPositionLimiter(playerX,playerY);` never gets executed because `userInputHandling()` calls itself.

Comment: I added  a `break;` after each case and also this is happening only when I use  `playerPositionLimiter(playerX,playerY);`, It worked well when i used it without the parameters (commented below `playerPositionLimiter(playerX,playerY);` )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take another look at your code:

```
if((posX>9||posY>9)||(posX<0||posY<0)){
    if(posX>9) posX=9;
    else if(posX<0) posX=0;
    else if(posY>9) posY=9;
    else if(posY<0) posY=0;
}}
```

It will enter into the `if` in all the problematic cases, but if there are two separate problems, like x < 0 and y > 9 in the same time, `posX` will be set to 0 and `posY` will remain unchanged. Fix suggestion:

```
if(posX>9) posX=9;
if(posX<0) posX=0;
if(posY>9) posY=9;
if(posY<0) posY=0;
```

The outer `if`s were removed and separate `if`s resolve each problem.

EDIT

Another problem is that `posX` and `posY` are local parameters, you will need to pass their reference to the function, since the `posX` and `posY` parameter will cease to exist after the function runs and the outer values will remain unchanged even if you stored the correct values in your parameters.

Comment: Did not solve the problem. I am printing the playerX and playerY co-ordinates (you can see them in the above screenshots) the playerX goes beyond 9 and then Y remains 0 if i keep moving right.

Comment: @PurpleShark my suggestion solved a bug. You have other bugs as well. posX and posY are local parameters, you will need to pass their reference to the function, since the posX and posY parameter will cease to exist after the function runs and the outer values will remain unchanged even if you stored the correct values in your parameters.

Comment: @PurpleShark Also, note how it is called: `playerPositionLimiter(playerX,playerY);` while that function is defined as `void playerPositionLimiter(int posY, int posX)`

Comment: Will I have to use pointers for that?  @Bob__ I fixed that thanks!

Comment: @LajosArpad That solved it. Do I accept this as the answer? (The comment solved it)

Comment: @PurpleShark I have added the contents of my comment to my answer. If the current version of my answer solved your problem, then you may want to accept it.